# Mysql быстрая сортировка по ФИО

Tags: mysql, сортировка, оптимизация, индексы

Есть табличка - 1млн человек, есть разные данные, внешние ключи и тд.
Необходимо быстро (насколько это возможно) выбрать из таблички данные, отсортированные по ФИО.

Слегка почитал про индексы, которые улучшают выборку.
Сделал индекс BTREE f_name + i_name + o_name, и по BTREE индексу для каждого поля.
При EXPLAIN ни один индекс не используется. Даже при ORDER BY f_name (одно поле) - не используется ничего.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть.

UPD1:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `division_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `i_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `o_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `check` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `addr_object_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addr_house_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addr_room` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `place_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_from` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_period` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_table_1` (`group_id`),
  KEY `FK_table_2` (`division_id`),
  KEY `FK_table_3` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `FK_table_4` (`place_id`),
  KEY `FK_table_5` (`category_id`),
  KEY `Index_F` (`f_name`),
  KEY `Index_I` (`i_name`),
  KEY `Index_FIO` (`f_name`,`i_name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Index_division` (`division_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` `id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table_2` FOREIGN KEY (`division_id`) REFERENCES `divisions` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table_3` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `table` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table_4` FOREIGN KEY (`place_id`) REFERENCES `places` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table_5` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=398351 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Запрос:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY f_name
```

Ответ:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, 'SIMPLE', 'cooperators', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 383343, 'Using filesort'
```

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа. Точная структура таблицы, сведения о наполнении и вариабельности, текст запроса и его EXPLAIN - необходимы.

Comment: @Akina, добавил кое-что в вопрос

Comment: @Akina, какие нужны сведения о наполнении? Данные самые разные приразные

Comment: Структура таблицы - это вывод `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, а не "сочинение на тему"...

Comment: @Akina, добавил SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: Ну остаётся сделать вывод, что, по мнению оптимизатора, дешевле сканить таблицу, не используя индекса. Что при получении всех полей всех записей без отбора, наверное, близко к истине... Попробуйте добавить хинт ``FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (`Index_F`)``. PS. А 255 символов под фамилию или там номер телефона - под этим скрыта какая-то мысль?

Answer (score 0):

Для ключа   KEY `Index_FIO` (f_name, i_name, o_name) - нарастить до 50 каждое поле.

```
KEY `Index_FIO` (f_name(50), i_name(50), o_name(50));
```

Тип индекса не сильно важен.

Потом сделайте

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY f_name, i_name, o_name
```

и расскажите, что получилось.

Comment: результат тот же. Я сделал explain запроса explain select * from table where f_name = 'Иванов' and i_name = 'Иван' order by f_name, i_name - explain показал что использован индекс Index_FIO. получается он не используется пока нет ограничений, где бы он помог (логично), но когда я пишу limit 10000, 100 - он не используется. Когда сортирую по id - используется ключ PRIMARY даже без условий

Comment: на limit 5000, 100 ключ используется, возможно у меня не хватает оперативной памяти, чтобы использовать ключ на большем лимите... или что то типа того. памяти 4гб

Comment: Да, вы правы. Бесполезно.